# Need help on NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor; in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, guava

There was a few other issues as this one but most of them were for android and I am currently working in IntelliJ with Java Gradle project.

My project is Gradle Java project in IntelliJ and I'm using Cloud Firestore as database. I am trying to make a .jar file so I can run the application, but it throws an exception.

I am probably doing something wrong when I when I create the .jar file because when I run the application in IntelliJ it works fine. The problem comes when I run the .jar file. The exception is as follows:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor;
at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl.<init>(ClientCallImpl.java:96)
at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl$RealChannel.newCall(ManagedChannelImpl.java:662)
at io.grpc.internal.CensusTracingModule$TracingClientInterceptor.interceptCall(CensusTracingModule.java:382)
at io.grpc.ClientInterceptors$InterceptorChannel.newCall(ClientInterceptors.java:104)
at io.grpc.internal.CensusStatsModule$StatsClientInterceptor.interceptCall(CensusStatsModule.java:675)
at io.grpc.ClientInterceptors$InterceptorChannel.newCall(ClientInterceptors.java:104)
at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcHeaderInterceptor.interceptCall(GrpcHeaderInterceptor.java:81)
at io.grpc.ClientInterceptors$InterceptorChannel.newCall(ClientInterceptors.java:104)
at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcMetadataHandlerInterceptor.interceptCall(GrpcMetadataHandlerInterceptor.java:55)
at io.grpc.ClientInterceptors$InterceptorChannel.newCall(ClientInterceptors.java:104)
at io.grpc.internal.ManagedChannelImpl.newCall(ManagedChannelImpl.java:636)
at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcClientCalls.newCall(GrpcClientCalls.java:66)
at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcDirectServerStreamingCallable.call(GrpcDirectServerStreamingCallable.java:65)
at com.google.api.gax.grpc.GrpcExceptionServerStreamingCallable.call(GrpcExceptionServerStreamingCallable.java:62)
at com.google.api.gax.rpc.WatchdogServerStreamingCallable.call(WatchdogServerStreamingCallable.java:69)
at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ServerStreamingCallable$1.call(ServerStreamingCallable.java:220)
at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ServerStreamingCallable$1.call(ServerStreamingCallable.java:220)
at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ServerStreamingCallable.serverStreamingCall(ServerStreamingCallable.java:166)
at com.google.api.gax.rpc.ServerStreamingCallable.serverStreamingCall(ServerStreamingCallable.java:178)
at com.google.cloud.firestore.FirestoreImpl.streamRequest(FirestoreImpl.java:339)
at com.google.cloud.firestore.Query.stream(Query.java:955)
at com.google.cloud.firestore.Query.get(Query.java:995)
at com.google.cloud.firestore.Query.get(Query.java:965)
at main.main(main.java:39)
```

Line 39 in main.java is:

```
ApiFuture<QuerySnapshot> query = db.collection("collectionName").get();
```

I read that there is some version problem with Guava but I can't exclude the dependency in my build.gradle. I tried everything that I found but nothing worked.

Again, the project works fine when I run the main method in IntelliJ but when I run the .jar it throws the exception.

I will appreciate if I can receive some tips on how to create the .jar file or if there is any useful info on the Guava and how to fix the dependency.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are using an old version of Guava. `com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors.directExecutor()Ljava/util/concurrent/Executor` has been introduced since Guava 18.0.

```
 * @since 18.0
 */
public static Executor directExecutor() {
  return DirectExecutor.INSTANCE;
}
```

See also:
https://github.com/google/guava/commit/495f60836c95faa28955a1183a92b0ecd3b50365#diff-7a493427c77df959295f1d55574dbd50

Please check your dependencies of Guava in `build.gradle` and try upgrading it.
If you are not using an old version, please click <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> on IntelliJ and then enter `com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors` to find the Guava jar which you are using.